# Python - IndentationError: expected an indented block on a if

Tags: python

I am new to python, so here is my problem.
I get the error "IndentationError: expected an indented block" on y_list in line 31 -> after the first if.
The file I load includes alot of numbers, and the idea is to skip the negative ones  in the socalled y_list.

```
filename = "data_5.dat" # this file can also be found in the sandbox folder 
x_list = []
y_list = []

fp = open(filename)
for line in fp:
    var1, var2  = line.split(",")    # here we wish to split the line using the ',' character

    # since we want them in numeric format we need to convert
    a = float(var1)
    b = float(var2)

    # put them into two lists
    x_list.append(a)
    y_list.append(b)

fp.close()    # close the file


x = x_list
y = y_list

I = 0.0
L = 0.0

for k in range(1, len(x)):
if y_list>0:
        y_list.append(y)
        I += y[k-1] * (x[k] - x[k-1])

for k in range(1, len(x)):
if y_list>0:
        y_list.append(y)
        L += y[k] * (x[k] - x[k-1])

print I
print L
print (I+L)/2
```

Comment: The both `if y_list>0:` lines should be indented by four spaces.

Comment: @eumiro, That may be an artifact of the Markup system. In plaintext, those lines are indented, but with tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: @Kevin: That is a *big hint* as to what is wrong here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k in range(1, len(x)):
if y_list>0:
        y_list.append(y)
        I += y[k-1] * (x[k] - x[k-1])
```

These `if` blocks are part of a `for` block, so they need to be indented one from them:

```
for k in range(1, len(x)):
    if y_list>0:
        y_list.append(y)
        I += y[k-1] * (x[k] - x[k-1])
```

The standard is to use four spaces, but it's common to run into problems like this if you're mixing tabs and spaces, even if it's technically valid Python.

Comment: Sorry about that. Wrote wrong here, but I got it your way in python

Answer (score 0):

Go to the line number 31 (then line 36 as well) and indent it. Hit the tab key at the beginning of the line so it'll stand out to the right a bit.

Comment: Not eight! Rather 3 spaces. `;)`

Comment: Not 3! Rather, 4 spaces. So sayeth the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: Not PEP8! Rather, I have my own unique sense of code beauty. `:)`

Comment: I used spaces in this coding so it would look better, bust using tab in python itself.

If i tab it one more time it skips out of the "if" and, dont it just be like if there was nothing inside the "if" at all?

Comment: @user2186583 I don't insist on inserting the ASCII 9 symbol a.k.a. a tab. You could as well use the PEP8-recommended 4 spaces. Most editors will allow you to configure the tab *key* accordingly.

Comment: @Martijn I'm being ironic here over the whole tabs-vs-spaces dispute. Actually it's very nice that PEP8 exists for Python.

Answer (score 0):

```py
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import base64

 if naujas==20:
      Ivestis=input('Iveskite failo varda kuri noresite koreguoti')

 file2 = open(Ivestis, 'r')

 failas=file2.read() file2.close() file4=open(Ivestis,'r+')

 bfailas=failas.encode("UTF-8") efailas=base64.b64encode(bfailas)
 print(efailas)



 # encoded _data has the encoded form of our text – ’see the source’


 efailas=str(efailas)

 file4.write(efailas)

 file4.close()

 elif naujas==20:

 file3 = open('Naujas.txt', 'r+') 


 naujas=base64.b64decode(file3.read())

 print(naujas)


 else

 print('Tikriausiai tokio failo nera')
```

Same

*Does't working :/